# Não consigo chamar Activity por minutos sem precisar de botão

Tags: android

Boa tarde,  estou começando a aprender ansdroid, e eu estou no senguinte aperto, eu não consigo fazer a troca de tela por minutos, aonde estou errando  e alguém pode me da um otimização?

```
public void passartelacategoria(View view) {
        final int MILISEGUNDOS = 3000;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent chamando = new Intent(MainActivity.this, categoriaActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(chamando);
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, MILISEGUNDOS);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

O código está correto, mas provavelmente por estar setando o tempo ali dentro do método e ainda por cima como final, pode estar influenciando.

Tenta declarar o tempo lá em cima na sua Activity, por exemplo:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static int TIME_OUT = 3000; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...
}
```